# Expected value of order statistics for samples drawn from poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, order-statistics

I want to find the expected value of the $k$-th [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of a sample with size $n$, drawn from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. More precisely, I want to find $E(X_{(k)})$ where $X_i$'s are sampled from a Poisson distribution with probability $P(X=k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^\lambda}{k!}$, and then sorted to find the $k$-th order statistic.

Is there any closed form interpretation of the expected value?

The solution to this problem can be used in finding an upper bound on the expected number of balls in a problem known as balls into bins problem which has a use case in chain hashing. It's worth mentioning that in that problem, the distribution of balls in each bin can be approximated by an independent Poisson distribution, so the answer to this question can be used there to approximate the expected number of balls in heavily loaded bins.

Answer (score 0):

Herbert A. David, H. N. Nagaraja - Order statistics-(2003) page 23.
$$F_k(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\sum_\limits{i=0}^{k-1}e^{- \lambda F(x)}\frac{[\lambda F(x)]^i}{i!} & x<b,\\
1 & x\geqslant b.
\end{cases}$$
Where $F(x)$ is cdf on $[a,b]$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1434963)

Comment: @Integrand. This is a direct link to where the answer is. So answer is not provided?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1434963)

Comment: @Mohsen Shahriari. As you can see link is paper book with fixed edition year. Do you think it can be changed? But, ok, I type part of it and you will see what you made me do.

Comment: @zkutch Both my comment and Integrand's are automatically generated when reviewing your post. These are not things that we've personally decided to force on you. These are just the standards under which this site works, and the community demands. I sincerely hope you haven't taken things personally.

Comment: @Mohsen Shahriari. I know. I'm sorry if I didn't put it very nicely. Last sentence is a sad half-joke of a peasant plowing the land ..

Comment: I don't think it's the right answer to my question. I'm seeking for a closed-form answer for the expected value of the order statistics while the page you mentioned is providing a probability for a different question.

Comment: @mahdi. I un-deleted my answer only for this question: on book and page which I find for you and formula I typed for you is  $k$-order Poisson cdf functions or it is not?

Comment: @zkutch The problem in the book is about particles with size $x$ with a cdf $F(x)$. The cdf function $F_k(x)$ is provided for order statistics of particle sizes which apparently is not distributed by a Poisson.

Comment: @mahdi. Formula brought by my directly start with assumption "(a) the number per unit area follows a Poisson law" and looking at formula itself, which formula we have for each summand?

Comment: @zkutch Yeah, I saw that, but the formula you provided is for the size of particles not for the number of them which has a Poisson distribution.